# Find rank of the space $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real polynomials .Consider the subspace $W$ spanned by $t^2+t+2; t^2+2t+5,5t^2+3t+4;2t^2+2t+4$.

Then find dimension of $W$ .

Now $\dim W$ will depend on the number of linearly independent elements among the four given.

Let $c_1(t^2+t+2)+c_2( t^2+2t+5)+c_3(5t^2+3t+4)+c_4(2t^2+2t+4)=0$.

So we get $c_1+c_2+5c_3+2c_4=0;c_1+2c_2+3c_3+2c_4=0;2c_1+5c_2+4c_3+4c_4=0$

In matrix form;

$A=$

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 5 & 2\\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 & 4 & 4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ c_4 \end{bmatrix} $=0$

What I got is that rank $A<3$.How can I find out $\dim W$ from here?

Comment: You may just calculate the rank of the coefficient matrix of these polynomials, (1,t,t^2 as basis)

Answer (score 1):

If you write your vectors as row-matrices, i. e. consider the transpose of $A$, and proceed to row-reduction, you don't have to resort to the rank-nullity theorem:
\begin{align*}
^{\mathrm t\!}A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2 \\ 1&2&5 \\ 5&3&4 \\2&2&4\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&-2&-6 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
At each step, the row-vectors span the same subspace as the initial one, since the transformations are reversible. The final state shows the subspace $W$ has dimension $2$.

Furthermore, as the first two final vectors are a basis for $W$ and we did not swap any vectors, we know the first two  given vectors are a basis for $W$.

Comment: Can u please explain why rank A=2 implies dim W=2

Comment: It's because $W$ is spanned by the row-vectors of $^{\mathrm t\!}A$. Isn't that clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the matrix into reduced row echelon form, you can find out the Row or Column rank. Then you can use the rank-nullity theorem to find the dimension of W.